# assign $_POST to private property of a public class PHP

Tags: php, oop, class, variables

I have some troubles trying to asign the `$_POST` value to a **property** inside my public class.

```
    class Sector
    {

    private $sectorName;
    private $sectorInfo;
    private $sectorCategory;

    private $errors;
    private $token;

    private $config;

    public function __constructor () 
    {
        $this->errors = array();
        $this->token  = $_POST['token'];

        $this->sectorName     = $_POST['secName'];
        $this->sectorInfo     = $_POST['secInfo'];
        $this->sectorCategory = $_POST['secCat'];

        $this->config = parse_ini_file('config.ini');
    }
```

The problem is that when I check if `$this->sectorName` is empty it always returns `true`.
But when I check if `$_POST['secName']` is empty it returns `false`.

**EDIT:** Here it is the function where I check if the property are empty and the `error_handler` function

```
public function show_errors () 
{
    echo "Errores: ";
    foreach($this->errors as $key => $value)
        echo $value . "<br/>";
}

public function valid_data () 
{
    if (empty($this->sectorName))
    {
        $this->errors [] = "Datos incorrectos";
    }

return count($this->errors)? 0 : 1;
}
```

Comment: Um, var_dump $_POST please

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are assuming that public function __constructor  is a constructor function, in actually it is not the magic function you should use __construct

```
public function __construct (
    $this->errors = array();
    $this->token  = $_POST['token'];

    $this->sectorName     = $_POST['secName'];
    $this->sectorInfo     = $_POST['secInfo'];
    $this->sectorCategory = $_POST['secCat'];

    $this->config = parse_ini_file('config.ini');
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that was my noob's error!